# What is the difference between width and device-width in CSS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, css, media-queries

What is the difference between `width` and `device-width` in CSS?

I know there have already been some questions around this, but I would like to understand these from a media query perspective to sniff browser/device, e.g. desktop/mobile/tablet.

Comment: Aren't those questions you speak of all about media queries too?

Comment: No..they do not stress on media queries, which is what i am looking for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The **device-width** and device-height features refer to the dimensions of the output device (that is, the screen size).
>
> The **width** and height features, on the other hand, refer to the dimensions of the rendering surface, which is the viewport (for example, the browser window) for screen media, or the page box for print media.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/mediaqueries#mediaqueries__tbl_media-queries_media-features

Comment: Ok..so my question is ; 1. Are both these things (width/device-width) same for mobile/tablet devices , but different for desktops ? 2. On the desktop, what would device-width indicate?

Comment: @testndtv: 1. No they aren't the same. 2. It would be your screen size, rather than say the browser window. Have a read of this article http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html but read part 1 first. It will give you a much better understanding of how it all works.